# Java Bubble Sorting Array Wrong Output

Tags: java, arrays, methods

just to preface, I am very new to coding in Java, or coding in general to be exact.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. It is a project, where we take a input file of numbers, one integer being a competitor number, the next being their weight for a fish they caught, (Looking like this 3 26.7 (new line per two numbers) 2 2.6.. so on and so on), put them in a array, then sort them in one way or another. Now, I will post the whole code, but it is only the last method, "sort", that I am having difficulties right now.

The method is a bubble sorting method. The way I am approaching it is so that it will take the first array, compare it with the second array to see if it is less than, then swap the two competitor numbers if the logic is correct so that I can print the competitor numbers in the main method, and call the appropriate weight for the competitor (which is previously compiled in past if/then loop). Note, I do not have it currently trying to print the competitor weight.

I believe I am on the right track for this, but for some reason, the numbers printed, after calling the sort method, are not correct. If you could tell me what I am doing wrong, that would be greatly helpful. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project8
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner inF = new Scanner(new File("data7.txt"));
        PrintWriter outF = new PrintWriter(new File("pro7out.txt"));
        int [] arrayNum = new int[7];
        int [] sortedNum = new int[7];
        double [] arrayWeight = new double[7];
        int place, firstplace, lastplace;
        double weight;
        String line;
        String entries[];
        outF.printf("My name - Project 7: 4/10/18%nResults of the Rocking JR Fishing Contest%n");
        outF.printf("Competitor      Total%n  Number        Weight%n");
            for (int m = 0; m < 7; m++)
                {
                    arrayNum[m] = m + 1;
                }
            while (inF.hasNextLine())
                {
                    line = inF.nextLine();
                    entries = line.split(" +");
                    place = Integer.parseInt(entries[0]);
                    weight = Double.parseDouble(entries[1]);
                    if (place == 1)
                        arrayWeight[0] += weight;
                    else if (place == 2)
                        arrayWeight[1] += weight;
                    else if (place == 3)
                        arrayWeight[2] += weight;
                    else if (place == 4)
                        arrayWeight[3] += weight;
                    else if (place == 5)
                        arrayWeight[4] += weight;
                    else if (place == 6)
                        arrayWeight[5] += weight;
                    else 
                        arrayWeight[6] += weight;    
                } 
            for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                outF.printf("%5d %15.2f%n", arrayNum[k], arrayWeight[k]);
        firstplace = first(arrayNum, arrayWeight);
        lastplace = last(arrayNum, arrayWeight);
        sortedNum = sort(arrayNum, arrayWeight);  
        outF.printf(" Winner is%n    %d           %3.2f%n", firstplace, arrayWeight[firstplace-1]);
        outF.printf(" Not as successful%n    %d            %3.2f%n", lastplace, arrayWeight[lastplace-1]);
            for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                outF.printf("%d", sortedNum[k]);
        outF.printf(" Contest Over%n");
        inF.close();
        outF.close();
    }
public static int first(int number[], double weight[])
    {
        int firstplace=0;
        double max=0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
            {
                if (weight[k] > max)
                    {
                        max = weight[k];
                        firstplace = number[k];
                    }
            }
        return firstplace;
    }
public static int last(int number[], double weight[])
    {
        int lastplace=0;
        double minimum=weight[0];
        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
            {
                if (weight[k] < minimum)
                    {
                        minimum = weight[k];
                        lastplace = number[k];
                    }
            }
        return lastplace;
    }  
public static int[] sort(int number[], double weight[])
{
    int n = number.length;
    int tempNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n-1); j++) 
                {
                    if (weight[j - 1] < weight[j]) 
                        {
                            tempNum = number[j - 1];
                            number[j - 1] = number[j];
                            number[j] = tempNum;   
                        }
                }
         }
    return number;    
}
```

}

Comment: Please **don't** use Javascript snippets for non-Javascript languages.

Comment: Bubblesort needs to loop while the array is not sorted. You loop over the length of the array.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: @notyou As in compiling it for errors? I have done that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Would you mind explaining that a little more? As I said, I am very new to all of this, and I am not sure how to execute what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: [here's your answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation).

Comment: During the sorting process, when you find two weights out of order, you're only the corresponding  competitor numbers; you also need to swap the weights themselves.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank you, I used a different method to sort it, and switched the weights. That was the problem.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Do you think you could answer my other question related to this?
Say arrayInt is equal to 2,4,6,5,1. I want to use a for loop to print the numbers. Then, I want to print the real number that is corresponding to the int. So, arrayInt, that is sorted, is 2,4,5,3,1; and say arrayDouble, isn't sorted, is 2.6, 6.9, 1.3, 2.4, 9.8. So , when I print array[0], it's = 2, then I want to print value 2 in arrayDouble (i.e. arrayDouble[1].

How might i do that?

Comment: That last scenario makes no sense. As I think you've just learned, you cannot rearrange the contents of just `arrayInt` without losing the relationship that originally existed between the numbers in `arrayInt` and the corresponding numbers in `arrayDouble`.